# start-stop-daemon: user 'neo4j' not known

Tags: neo4j

I've installed neo4j to a VM running Ubuntu (on the koding dot com platform). It shows in a dpkg-query so I'm sure its installed.

To start the server I use the command:
    sudo service neo4j-service start

This doesn't start the sservice but generates and error message:
    start-stop-daemon: user 'neo4j' not known

Should I start again, removing the packagage and reinstalling? Or is there a way to add this user or to use the root user?

Comment: I reinstalled the package and it added the user neo4j.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reinstall the package to add the user 'neo4j'.